# Ruby optparse - how to use it in a script?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby, I'm writing a script that does the following:

1. Accepts command line arguments
2. Deletes a few directories based on specifying an argument.

What I want it to do:

```
./admin_bin -c
Removing files in /opt/sysnovo/tmp and /opt/sysnovo/data
```

I have this working! But... it's not in a *rubyish* way.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'fileutils'
require 'optparse'


OptionParser.new do |o|
    o.on('-c') { |b| $clear = b }
    o.on('-h') { puts o; exit }
    o.parse!
end

# Two directories we want to specify.
tmp_dir = "/opt/sysnovo/tmp"
data_dir = "/opt/sysnovo/data"

# push this value to a variable so we can evaluate it.
test = $clear

if "#{test}" == "true"
    puts "Removing files in #{tmp_dir} and #{data_dir}"
    FileUtils.rm_rf("#{tmp_dir}/.", secure: true)
    FileUtils.rm_rf("#{data_dir}/.", secure: true)
else
    puts "Not removing files."
end
```

As you can see, I set $clear to #{test} and evaluate based on that. I know it's not correct. What's the correct way to do this? I'll be adding more arguments and functionality to this script later on.

P.S. I come from a bash background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option Parser use the True/False class to set the flags. You test should look like this :

If you do `$clear.class` => TrueClass. It's a bool.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'
require 'optparse'


OptionParser.new do |o|
    o.on('-c') { |b| $clear = b }
    o.on('-h') { puts o; exit }
    o.parse!
end

# Two directories we want to specify.
tmp_dir = "/opt/sysnovo/tmp"
data_dir = "/opt/sysnovo/data"

# push this value to a variable so we can evaluate it.

if $clear
    puts "Removing files in #{tmp_dir} and #{data_dir}"
    FileUtils.rm_rf("#{tmp_dir}/.", secure: true)
    FileUtils.rm_rf("#{data_dir}/.", secure: true)
else
    puts "Not removing files."
end
```

You also only need to `require 'rubygems'` if you are using ruby <1.9.

Comment: Thank you! 

Now when I start to add other functionality (I guess this is style?), would I keep just using if statements to do so? Or is there a more ruby way to do it? In bash I might of used functions. Would this be a good script to start using classes in?

Not sure I want to do something like:
`if $clear
  # whatever
end`

`if $somethingelse
  #do whatever
end`

etc

Comment: One other question. What is this code doing: `{ |b| $clear = b }`

Comment: You would just keep going with the `if` statements. If you never reusing code you don't really need method/class at this point. Just do a linear flow. `{|b| c = b}` the object is passed to `b`, you then set `c` to `b`.